# Reflection on AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, reflection

I can't see how an empty protocol changes the ability to reflect on an object. Is reflection on `AnyObject` generally not possible? If so, why is that?

Example:

```
protocol Protocol {}

struct Bar : Protocol {
    let bar: String
}

let bar = Bar(bar: "bar") as Protocol

for (label, value) in Mirror(reflecting: bar).children {
    print("property: \(label!), value: \(value)")
}
```

prints

```
property: bar, value: bar
```

whereas

```
struct Baz {
    let baz: String
}

let baz = Baz(baz: "baz") as AnyObject

for (label, value) in Mirror(reflecting: baz).children {
    print("property: \(label!), value: \(value)")
}
```

prints

(well, nothing.)

Comment: you destroy the type when you cast to AnyObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the type, use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`, e.g.

```
let anyBaz = Baz(baz: "baz") as Any

var anyBazMirror = Mirror(reflecting:anyBaz)
var anyBazType = anyBazMirror.subjectType

print(anyBazType == Baz.self)  // true

for (label, value) in anyBazMirror.children {
    print("any property: \(label!), value: \(value)")
}
```

---

### Now, what's the thing about `AnyObject`?

As the name suggests, `AnyObject` is intended to represent any *object*. So in a perfect world, we would expect a compiler error saying that your struct `Baz` is not a reference type and therefore not an object and therefore cannot be casted to such.

Thanks to the Object C legacy, we sometimes need a behaviour like "casting" values to objects, because many types in Swift - like Arrays, Strings etc. - are value types, but the Objective C API expectes objects.

Therefore there are some compiler tricks to minimize manual casting orgies. If you cast a value type to `AnyObject`, the compiler is *boxing* your value into an intermediate type by calling the internal function  `Swift._bridgeAnythingToObjectiveC`:

[image]

This boxing results in some strange intermediate internal type, which you can see when using e.g. `print(String(describing: baz))`:

> __lldb_expr_77.Baz(baz: "baz")

Nevertheless, it's just bridged, **not *destroyed***. If can cast it back to the structure it was, you get the full monty again:

```
// from above: 
// let baz = Baz(baz: "baz") as AnyObject

let bazStruct = baz as! Baz
for (label, value) in Mirror(reflecting: bazStruct).children {
    print("property: \(label!), value: \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, that doesn't solve my problem if I don't know in advance which class the object belongs to

Comment: If you want to know the type, use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` (see above)

Comment: This answer looks quite complete. I think it would be a good idea to move the "To keep the type, use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` [...]" part to the top and leave the rest for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Casting an instance to `AnyObject` will destroy the type of that instance.

In your situation a generic type might fix your issue.

```
func checkProperties<T: Any>(of instance: T) {

    let children: Mirror.Children

    children = Mirror(reflecting: instance).children

    children.forEach {
        print($0.label, $0.value)
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function on any object without casting like this:

```
checkProperties(of: Baz(baz: "baz"))
```

This means that the function needs any instance inherited from `Any` but it will keep it's type

Comment: I'm not sure if "[...] will destroy the type of that instance" is technically correct, as I can do `Baz(baz: "baz") as AnyObject as! Baz` without any problems.

Comment: Using `Any` was what I was looking for, though. It worked for my problem. Thanks

Comment: `Baz(baz: "baz") as AnyObject as! Baz` will cast back to the original type so the type is kinda restored